# Show notifications in action center setting not working for Slack

Tags: windows-10, notifications, action-center

On Windows 10, in `Settings > Notifications & Actions` I have notifications turned on for Slack.  If I click on Slack it takes me to more notification settings for Slack.  On that screen I have `Show notification banners` set to On and `Show notifications in action center` set to Off.

I do see the toast-style banners pop up when I get a Slack message.  But I also see those same notifications in the action center, which makes me wonder if I'm misunderstanding the setting.

Is there a way to have the toast banners and not have the notifications collect like so much sediment in the action center?

Comment: Did you try to disable Slack notifications in Settings? This should leave only banners active.

Comment: I tried leaving the "show notification banners" set to on, while setting the "notifications" off for Slack and now the banners don't show up :(  It looks like "notifications" off kills everything.

Comment: I have the same issue an am still looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no way of eating your cake and keeping it too: it's an all or nothing setting in Windows 10.

What I did was turning it off entirely on Windows 10:

- I still see the red or blue ball on the slack icon itself and can hear the slack notification sound
- My phone still pings me and shows the message if I don't read it within a minute or so.

**¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

Answer (score 0):

Slack periodically continues to stop display notifications on my MacOS (latest and previous) and Windows (10).
Of course I tried all options/workaround.
Focus / Do not disturn - Disabled. Notificaitons - enabled. Etc!

To fix this:

1. go to Slack Settings,
2. Change Notification type to another, Then immediately revert it back (for example: use native SLACK)
3. Click on "Show an example"
4. and save/close the settings.

Now notification works again until next app grab the focus or something broke in the Slack again.

Another option that may work (or not ):

1. Type in the any message box to open the Slack dev tools (for example: here):

   /slackdevtools
2. This will open in a new Slack (chromium!) window with bunch of console logs being printed. In the "Console" input box at the very bottom designated by the > symbol, copy and paste the code at the bottom of this post and hit Enter.

   notificationFailoverEnabled:false
3. Refresh Slack windows: cmd+R or ctrl+r

PS Notifications works perfect on my Ubuntu 20.04 .

Comment: Is this from ChatGPT?